# How do I add shared dependencies to a monorepo using Yarn workspaces?

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I am using Yarn's Workspaces feature to manage a monorepo. Some of the individual workspaces have their own dependencies defined in their own `package.json`, however I also have some shared dependencies (some are for testing the whole repo, some are used by all the workspaces). How do I declare these the correct way?

If I try to add them to the root `package.json`, Yarn gives me a warning. But adding the same dependency to all `n` workspaces (there are a lot and it's liable to grow) seems tedious and hard to maintain when upgrading dependencies.

Is the right thing to do to add the shared dependency (say, `typescript`, or `jest` or `serverless`) to every single individual workspace?

Using Yarn 1/classic.

I found also [Yarn Workspaces: How and where should I install my dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66087634/yarn-workspaces-how-and-where-should-i-install-my-dependencies) but it's unanswered
[Yarn workspaces shared dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66243278/yarn-workspaces-shared-dependencies) talks about using peer dependencies but the user is experiencing trouble

Answer (score 15):

After a half-day search and trying, I found multiple ways to manage shared dependencies

**1. Sync dependency version with [syncpack](https://github.com/JamieMason/syncpack/)**

https://github.com/JamieMason/syncpack/

Given the fact that yarn workspaces will share the dependencies if their versions are the same (see https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/), all we have to do is to keep the dependency versions in sync to make dependencies sharing, which is exactly what syncpack does.

I found this is the least harmful way to make sharing dependencies works, while other methods require some degree of twisting package.json.

**2. Use peer dependencies**

For each package, set sharing dependencies as peerDependencies with version “*”, and set root workspace set the real dependencies. For example:

```json
# ./package.json
{   
    ...
    "workspaces": ["packages/*"],
    "dependencies": [
        "some-lib": "^1.0.0",
    ]
}

# ./packages/pkg-a/package.json
{
    ...
    "peerDependencies": [
        "some-lib": "*",
    ]
}
```

and `yarn install` at workspace root.

**3. Share script (require yarn v2)**

See https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/qa#how-to-share-scripts-between-workspaces

**Miscellaneous**

yarn provides workspace cli to add/remove package, see https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/workspace/

```sh
yarn workspace awesome-package add react react-dom --dev

yarn workspace web-project remove some-package
```

Comment: can you elaborate on approach 2? facing a similar issue in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72967617/command-not-found-react-scripts-ps-yarn2berry-workspaces

Comment: Hi, did approach 2 worked for anyone, I am having a similar issue and mentioning the shared dependency in "peerDepencies" is not working

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. Approach 2 works for my case but does not guarantee as a general solution. I would recommend "approach 1" to go. Yarn 1 is just not built for mono repos.